# reading in parallel from" generator in Keras

Tags: parallel-processing, keras, generator

I have a big dataset divided in files.
I would like to read and process my data one file at the time and for this I have this keras generator:

```
def myGenerator():
   while 1:
       rnd = random.randint(1,200)
       strRnd = str(rnd)
       lenRnd = len(strRnd)
       rndPadded = strRnd.rjust(5, '0') 
       nSearchesInBatch = 100
       f = "path/part-" + rndPadded + "*" #read one block of data

       data = sqlContext.read.load(f).toPandas()

       imax = int(data.shape[0]/nSearchesInBatch) #number of batches that will be created sequentially from the generator

       for i in range(imax):
       data_batch = data[i*nSearchesInBatch:(i+1)*nSearchesInBatch]

       features = data_batch['features']
       output = data_batch['output']

       yield features, output
```

The problem is that the reading takes the biggest part (each file is around 200mb), and in the meanwhile the GPU sits waiting, it is possible to pre-read the next batch while the GPU is traning on the previous one?

At the moment one file is read and split in steps (the inner loop), the CPUs are hidden and the GPU training, as soon as the epoch finishes, the GPU goes idle and the cpu start reading (which takes 20/30 seconds).

Any solution to parallelize this?

Comment: Keras indeed reads from generator in parallel (as long as you set `max_queue_size` and `workers` both > 1). The problem is that creating a dataframe with pyspark in a generator is too slow. Maybe you can pre-convert your data into some on-disk formats (e.g., `np.memmap` or hdf5 with `pytables`).

Comment: What I noticed is that the pyspark job (sqlContext.read.load(f).toPandas()) doesn't start until the whole previous batch is consumed in the training.

I tried creating a thread safe generator, with 4 workers and queue > 150, but i can't see any difference

The spark job starts, then it finishes, then there is a bit of time before the progress bar of the training appears (where it does some pre-processing on the data that i omitted in the inner loop). And the next spark job doesn't start until the gpu goes idle.

Comment: Do you find a solution ?Thanks !